# AWS Mobile iOS SDK not building AWSCognitoSyncService correctly (fails)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

This was building previously but isn't anymore. I updated cocoapods and pulled new data in with pod update but still can't build my iOS 9.0 app anymore:

```
/Users/cdub/Developer/AppName/Pods/Headers/Public/
AWSCognito/AWSCognitoSyncService.h:198:4: 
Type arguments cannot be applied to non-parameterized class 'AWSTask'
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The version of `AWSCore` and `AWSCognito` need to match. It looks like your `AWSCognito` is newer than `AWSCore`. How did you get `AWSCognito` and `AWSCore`? Both through CocoaPods? You need to use `pod update` when updating the pods instead of `pod install`.

If you keep encountering the issue, you should delete `Podfile.lock` and `Pods/` and then run `pod install` to cleanly install the SDK. [AWS Mobile SDK iOS Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html#id2) has more information about how to setup the SDK.

Comment: Rebuilt everything again. Still fails. Did pod update first. Then reinstalled after deleting Pods and podfile and reinstalled AWS IOS SDK 2.3.6 and same error. What gives?

Comment: Nevermind. It was none of the above. The frameworks build path only had certain frameworks in their somehow and I copied the ones over from the new SDK and put it all in the <project name>/frameworks and things are working now. I wonder how the frameworks folder got messed up